# How to cross compile Raspberry Pi project on x86_64? (missing *.so due to invalid path)

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, cross-compiling, raspberry-pi

I am cross compiling Raspberry Pi project on x86_64/Ubuntu 13.04. After invoking **cmake** with:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=./Toolchain-raspberry.pi .
```

and then **make**, linking fails:

```
/opt/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.7.2/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_gpu
...
```

The problem is that **cmake** generated Makefile invokes linker in the following way:

```
/opt/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++       CMakeFiles/Watson.dir/main.cpp.o  -o Watson -rdynamic -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_video -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_flann -lopencv_core
```

and it does not specify paths to those shared libraries. However, if I manually add **--sysroot /opt/rpi-rootfs/** flag to the command above, then linking succeeds.

**What is the recommended way to get cmake to specify the right paths to the shared libraries when cross compiling?**

Here is my **Toolchain-raspberry.pi** file:

```
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)

SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /opt/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /opt/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++)

SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH "/opt/rpi-rootfs/")
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

And this is my **CMakeList.txt** file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(watson)
add_executable(Watson main.cpp)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(Watson ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

The /usr and /lib directories from the target are rsync'ed to /opt/rpi-rootfs/ and all the necessary *.so files are there. After reading **cmake** documentation, I would have expected that setting **CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH** would solve this problem, but apparently not. I am using **cmake** version 2.8.10.1.

Comment: Have you tried to use [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/) or [OpenEmbedded](http://www.openembedded.org/wiki/Main_Page)? As far as I can see you're using Debian (at least on RPi), have you looked at [xapt stuff](https://wiki.debian.org/EmdebianToolchain)?

Comment: See this [blog](http://blog.galemin.com/tag/opencv/) for BR example/image.

Comment: Have you been able to solve the problem?

Comment: Did you try [Qemu-User-static](https://wiki.debian.org/QemuUserEmulation "It just wrap instructions and system calls to the native kernel") for compiling natively?

Answer (score 0):

By my pratice,

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/opt/rpi-rootfs/usr/include)
LINK_DIRECTORIES(
    /opt/rpi-rootfs/usr/lib
    /opt/rpi-rootfs/lib
)
```

will work